# add folder to bundle when building mac installer using javapackager

Tags: java, deployment, javafx, javapackager

I've used [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html) to create installer for my java program, in order to run into mac OS X. There is some files and a single folder which needs to be bundle while performing the bundalation process from javapackager. My programs folder structure looks like this:

[image]

Now I issued the following command from terminal:

```
$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javapackager -deploy -native dmg -Bruntime=jre1.8.0_65.jre/ -srcfiles IPSettingScreen.jar  -srcfiles configuration.properties -srcfiles vremployee.jar -srcdir "native" -appclass ipsettingscreen.IPSettingScreen -name vr-employee -outdir deploy/ -outfile vr-employee -v
```

It sucessfully bundeld into the vr-employee.dmg, now if I installed vr-employee.dmg and look into the program installation directory there I could not found **native** folder which is library folder. In order to run my java program that native folder should be exist.
Now my question is how to add folder into that bundled? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Try to simply replace

```
-srcdir "native"
```

with

```
-srcfiles native
```

in your command

Comment: It only works with windows native bundeling process but It doesn't work with Mac OS. anyway thanks for your reply

Comment: I tested it successfully on Mac OS X 10.11.2 and JDK 1.8.0_66

Comment: I can find my folder and its content in my app file under Contents/Java/.

Comment: Adding it twice, one for a folder and one for the executable jar did the trick. Thanks